# 6 .htaccess Rewrites: Remove index.html, Remove .html, Force non-www, Force Trailing Slash

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i've to give some information about my website Environment

1. i have static webpage in the root.
2. Wordpress installed in sub-dictionary www.domain.com/blog/
3. I have two .htaccess , one in the root and one in the wordpress
   folder.

i want to

- www to non on all URLs **< below code DID it :)**
- Remove index.html from url **< below code DID it :)**
- Remove all .html extension / Re-direct 301 to url
  without .html extension  **< below code DID it :)**
- Add trailing slash to the static webpages / Re-direct 301 from non-trailing slash **<< I NEED HELP WITH THAT**
- Force trailing slash to the Wordpress Webpages / Re-direct 301 from non-trailing slash **< below code DID it :)**

Some examples

domain.tld/index.html >> domain.tld/

domain.tld/file.html >> domain.tld/file/

domain.tld/file.html/ >> domain.tld/file/

domain.tld/wordpress/post-name >> domain.tld/wordpress/post-name/

My code in ROOT htaccess is

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews


    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase /

    #removing trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d     
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

    #www to non
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?domain\.com)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    #html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

    #index redirect 
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/ 
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://domain.com/ [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L] 
    </IfModule> 

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /blog/
    # Force Trailing Slash for wordpress
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)[^/]{1}$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
    </IfModule>
```

The above code do

1. redirect www to non-www
2. Remove trailing slash at the end (if exists)
3. Remove index.html
4. Remove all .html
5. Redirect 301 to filename without trailing slash at the end
6. Force Trailing Slash for wordpress and redirect 301 from non trailing slash at the end

### EDIT

```
#removing trailing slash Rule usage
```

[image: removing trailing slash Rule]

Comment: See also RFC 2606.

Comment: Just to understand one of your examples. Do you want to access domain.tld/file/ on your browser and the server sends you the file domain.tld/file.html ?

Comment: i want to force trailing slash and redirect  301 domain.tld/file to domain.tld/file/

Comment: Ok, but what about this example you wrote: "domain.tld/file.html >> domain.tld/file/" ?
Do you want to access domain.tld/file/ on your browser and the server sends you the file domain.tld/file.html ?

Comment: @André Bonna The original URL was domain.tld/file.html and the above code stripped the html and redirect 301 to domain.tld/file , Now i want to redirect it to domain.tld/file/

Comment: If you want to add a trailing slash then why do you have `#removing trailing slash` rule?

Comment: @anubhava
Example : domain.com/file.html/ 
To strip the trailing slash first before stripping .html

Comment: @anubhava check the Edit , Thanks

Comment: You need to keep WP specific rules in `/blog/.htaccess` not in main .htaccess. What are example URLs where you want to add trailing slash.

Comment: @anubhava   Everything with Wordpress is OK now , The problem with the static webpages

i need to add trailing slash for the static webpages 

[link](http://ghadaalsaman.com/articles) , [link](http://ghadaalsaman.com/books) , [link](http://ghadaalsaman.com/poem-list) , [link](http://ghadaalsaman.com/en/poem-list)

Comment: ok in that case my original comment. What is purpose of `#removing trailing slash` rule?

Comment: Because the code won't strip the html extension if there's a trailing slash at the end . 
Example : Here's the static webpage Original link is 

http://ghadaalsaman.com/articles.html/ (trailing slash at the end)

1 - the #removing trailing slash rule will strip the trailing slash
so it will be 
http://ghadaalsaman.com/articles.html (without trailing slash at the end.)

2- The #html rule will strip the html 
So it will be 
http://ghadaalsaman.com/articles

Now i want a rule to add trailing slash at the end / redirect 301 from non slash .
If you have a better code please suggest it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have it this way for site root .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

#www to non
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ http://%1/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html/?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,NE,L]

#index redirect 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]

# add a trailing slash to non files
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# add html internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/$ $1.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava but it's not working for  
http://ghadaalsaman.com/poem-list.html << it gives 500 error,
http://ghadaalsaman.com/en/poem-list << and for that file ,
Please open http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php and check how many redirects for that page http://ghadaalsaman.com/books.html/

Comment: how to reduce the redirects and make it 301 not 302
Thanks in addvanced

Comment: Thanks for your update , Everytthing is ok now , can i change the final redirect from 302 to 301 ?

Comment: Thanks , i changed that code  
'RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html/?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,NE,L]'

To

'RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html/?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,NE,L]'
but its still redirecting 302 not 301
the page i'm checing its redirect is 
http://ghadaalsaman.com/articles.html

Comment: No it is redirecting with 301 when I requested `http://ghadaalsaman.com/books.html/`. You have old browser cache issue.

Comment: As you can see redirect rule is same for all `*.html` so if one is showing 301 and another .html is showing 302 then it is due to some other reason not the rule.

Comment: Ops Please Help me the sitemap gives 404 because the trailing slash at the end , How to expect xml files? 
Here's the xml sitemap
http://ghadaalsaman.com/blog/sitemap.xml
and it was working on 
http://ghadaalsaman.com/sitemap.xml
Because google asks for the sitemap to be in the root

Comment: Both `sitemap.xml` links are working fine in my testing. Trailing slash won't be added to files due to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition.

Comment: it works after i've added that line 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sitemap [NC]
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteBase /
```

WWW to Non

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain\.tld$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Remove index.html from url

```
RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [L,R=301]
```

Remove all .html extension / Re-direct 301 to url without .html extension

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9]+).html$ /$1   [L,R=301]
```

Add trailing slash to the static webpages / Re-direct 301 from non-trailing slash

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z0-9]+).html$ /$1/   [L,R=301]
```

Force trailing slash to the Wordpress Webpages / Re-direct 301 from non-trailing slash

```
RewriteRule /blog/([^/]+) /blog/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but your solution seems to be not working.

Comment: @GhadaAlSamman Where do you place the `.htaccess` for the code in this answer?

Comment: In root .htaccess File