# Redirect 301 from non trailing slash to trailing slash at the end

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've installed Wordpress in subdirectory domain.com/blog/ 
The problem with the trailing slash , Wordpress posts gives 200 OK http for the two versions domain.com/blog/post-name and domain.com/blog/post-name/

i want to force trailing slash at the end and redirect 301 from non slash to trailing slash at the end

so trailing slash version gives 200 OK ONLY

my code

```
# Force Trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is at the regex: ^[^/]+$

This regex matches every string without ANY slash, so a string like domain.com/blog would not match. The best way to achieve your goal is like the following:

```
# Force Trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)[^/]{1}$
RewriteRule (.*) $1/ [L,R=301]
```

If you are using the default [wordpress htaccess file](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) you should do like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Force Trailing Slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)[^/]{1}$
    RewriteRule (.*) $1/ [L,R=301]


    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks it's working like a charm , Please take a look on that issue 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733574/6-htaccess-rewrites-remove-index-html-remove-html-force-non-www-force-trai

Thanks

Comment: The problem now with the static webpages, it's redirect to domain.com/articles not domain.com/articles/
the details on the other post 
Thanks in advanced

Comment: Sorry, I didn't undestand the problem with the static webpages. Can you specify a bit more?

Comment: Please check below link , i've explained everything there 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733574/6-htaccess-rewrites-remove-index-html-remove-html-force-non-www-force-trai